# How to understand produce optical standing wave by mirror reflecting with half-wave loss

Tags: optics, optical-lattices

Considering the incident optical wave $E_i=e^{ikx}$ and reflect optical wave $E_r=e^{-ikx+i\pi}$,where $\pi$ corresponding the half wave loss.The superposition of incident wave and reflect wave is $E=i2sin(kx)$.but generally we only conside the real part of E as the real existence of optical. it seems no optics existence in E. How to understanding this result? Dose it means a standingwave be produced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question you consider only the phasor part and omit the time part. If we include the time part as well, we obtain
$$
E_{tot} = e^{i(kx-wt)} + e^{i(kx+wt+\pi)}
= e^{ikx} \big[ e^{-iwt} - e^{-iwt} \big]
= 2i e^{ikx} \sin{(wt)}
$$
Taking the real part of this expression yields
$
\Re\{E_{tot}\} = 2\sin(kx)\sin{(wt)}
$. This is a standing wave with a knot at $x=0$, as expected. (Also note that yo are missing the complex number $i$ in front of $\pi$).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: The optical potential is usually writen as $Vsin^2(kx)$. Does it average the time part ？